# How to make this while loop finish on new line

Tags: arrays, c, loops, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int lista[9999];
    int a;
    int i = 0;

    while (scanf(" %d", &a) == 1)
    {
        lista[i] = a;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting an input of integers and spaces in between them, I do NOT want to read this with one `scanf` because there will be some calculations done depending on the integer. How to make this loop finish on a new line? `if (a == "\n")` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Read a whole line with `fgets`. Check if it's "empty" (only contains the newline) and exit the loop. Otherwise use e.g. `sscanf` to parse the number in it.

Comment: OT: "_I do NOT want to read this with one scanf because..._" Good design doesn't mingle processing with input... Fill the array in one phase, then traverse the array _tweaking_ values according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the behavior of `scanf()` for `%d` on newline characters. There are alternatives:

- you can read the whole input line with `fgets()` (or `getline()` on POSIX systems) and parse the numbers on the line with `strtol()` or `sscanf()`.
- you can read one integer at a time as a string with `scanf("%[-+0-9]", buf)` and convert them with `atoi()`, `strtol()` or `sscanf()`.
- you can read one character at a time with `getchar()` and convert the numbers on the fly, stopping at the newline character.

Here is an example using `scanf()` and `strtol()` with format validation:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int lista[9999];
    char buf[20];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 9999) {
        scanf("%*[ ]");  // skip spaces if any
        if (scanf("%19[-+0-9]", buf) != 1)
            break;
        errno = 0;
        char *p;
        long n = strtol(buf, &p, 10);
        if (p == buf || errno != 0 || *p != '\0'
        ||  n < INT_MIN || n > INT_MAX) {
            printf("invalid number: %s\n", buf);
            continue;
        }
        int a = (int)n;
        lista[i] = a;
        i++;
    }
    if (scanf("%1[\n]", buf) != 1) {
        // no trailing newline
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an alternative using just `getchar()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int lista[9999];
    int i = 0;
    int c = getchar();
    while (i < 9999) {
        while (c == ' ')
            c = getchar();
        int sign = c;
        if (c == '+' || c == '-')
            c = getchar();
        if (!isdigit(c))
            break;
        unsigned value = c - '0';
        while (isdigit(c = getchar()))
            value = value * 10 + (c - '0'); 
        a = (sign == '-') ? -value : value;
        lista[i] = a;
        i++;
    }
    if (c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        // extra input on the line
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use `fgets()`**

Read a *line* with `fgets()` into a generous buffer and then parse it for several `int`.

- Read 1 line.
- If user input line is longer than the generous input buffer, than additional code needed to handle that.
- A better alternative involves `strtol()`, yet this code use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` to take OP only a few steps away from `scanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LIST_N 9999
#define STR_LEN_INT 11  /* e.g. "-2147483647" */

int main(void) {
  int lista[LIST_N];
  // Form a buffer 2x expected needs of LIST_N * [a number and space].
  // This is getting big so code could malloc it, but as is for simplicity.
  char line[LIST_N * (STR_LEN_INT + 1) * 2];
  char *s = line;
  int i = 0;
  // Read in one line
  if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
    for (i = 0; i < LIST_N; i++) {
      int len = 0;
      // Scan for an int and record the offset of a successful scan.
      // Break from loop early is scan failed.
      if (sscanf(s, "%d %n", &lista[i], &len) != 1) {
        break;
      }
      // Advance to next part of the string.
      s += len;
    }
  }
  printf("int scanned count: %d.\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**If one *must* use `scanf()` ...**

Repeatedly:

- Look at the leading white-spaces for a `'\n'`.
- Then scan for an `int`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LIST_N 9999

int main(void) {
  int lista[LIST_N];
  int i = 0;

  while (1) {
    // Scan and toss various white-spaces, except \n.
    scanf("%*[ \f\r\t\v]"); 

    // Scan for a \n
    char eol[2];
    if (scanf("%1[\n]", eol) == 1) {
      break; 
    }

    // Scan for an int
    int a;
    if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (i < LIST_N) {
      lista[i++] = a;
    }
  }

  printf("int scanned count: %d.\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```